# PHP regular expression issue preg_match() on timestamps

Tags: php, regex

Facing issue with regular expression

`2013-05-29 15:15:12` string I am matching with `/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})({\s}+(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}))?$/` with `preg_match` but not validating ... its giving `false`.

What should be regexp to match **2013-05-29 15:15:12** or **2013-05-29** pattern.

Comment: Are you sure there are no stray whitespaces before or after your string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at your regex first. Between the date and the time you're matching `{\s}+`. This means "*the character `{`, followed by a space/tab, followed by one or more `}`'s*".

Replace `{\s}` with `?:\s+` (a non capturing group matching one or more spaces/tabs) so the full regex is

```
^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})(?:\s+(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}))?$
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/jX9yJ1)

Comment: You took the time to demo it, putting you unfairly behind in time. +1.

Comment: what does **?:**  do in ^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})(?:\s+(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}))?$

Comment: @PoonamBhatt It specifies a `non capturing group` meaning we will not save the match when matching (now you only have 6 matches, `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, `minute` and `second` instead of also having `hour:minute:second` as a match.) Try to look at the demo and remove the `?:` part to see what happens.

Comment: @PoonamBhatt Check out [**this**](http://regex101.com/r/jX9yJ1) and [**this**](http://regex101.com/r/nT5lH1) and look at the differences in the matches on the right.

Answer (score 2):

The `{\s}+` is wrong. It should be `\s+`. The curly brackets are used as quantifiers or literals only.